# android volley does not post all data to server

Tags: php, android, mysql, sockets, tcp

I am using Volley and sending my data with post to the mysql server.The problem is not all the messages are send to my server sometime some data get missed out or get lost.

After googling i found the answer that i should use socket which is good and gurantee post delivery can some one tell me should i use socket or Volley if socket the can some one show me the code how to send post data to server below is my volley and server code because i really don't know how to use android scoket with php.

**Volley code**

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("data1", "newdata1");
            obj.put("data2","newdata1");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                "http://*****/send_message.php", obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            response.getString("success");
                    ShowToast(response.getString);  
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

And my php script are as follow

**send_message.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['data1'])){

    $data = $_POST['data1'];
    $data2 = $_POST['data2'];
  ...............
}
?>
```